# Modify my SELECT statement to consider a certain Word

Tags: php, mysql

How would I make my SELECT statement check if a certain Title begins with a word and to display it at the bottom of the list? Please see my example below.

```
<?php
    @$DBn = new mysqli('localhost','REMOVED','REMOVED','REMOVED');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    else {
        $Queryn = "SELECT Title FROM Courses where Status = 'Live' order by Title";
        $Resultn = $DBn->query($Queryn);
        $NumResults = $Resultn->num_rows;

        while ($Rown = $Resultn->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<li><a href='http://www.domain.com/course-detail.php?Title=". $Rown['Title'] ."'>". $Rown['Title']  ."</a></li> \n";
        }
    }
?>
```

The above code will select every Title from Courses and display it in alphabetical order. How can I make it so if the Course begins with the word "Refresher" it will place that at the bottom after the last Course?

Course A,
Course B,
Course C,
Course D,
Refresher Course A,
Refresher Course B,
Refresher Course C,
Refresher Course D

The Table structure is as follows.
[image: Table Structure]

Comment: Please provide table structure for more info.

Comment: Use `LIKE`: `WHERE Title LIKE 'Refresher%'`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Title
FROM Courses
WHERE Status = 'Live'
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN Title LIKE 'Refresher%' THEN NULL ELSE Title END) IS NULL ASC,
    Title DESC
```

Follow the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de7a84/6)

Comment: Missing single quote?

Comment: This returns nothing.

Comment: This has definitely done something as there are now 6 Refresher courses at the top of the list but the rest are not in alphabetical order? Why would that be? Some of the courses without Refresher... are also in the top section with Refresher courses.

Comment: Try again.  I changed the query.